# fee basis points calculation in rust

Tags: anchor, rust, math, decimal

This is more of a general rust question but feels like a common enough situation when writing solana contracts such that I feel justified in asking it here.

Suppose I have a token with decimals set to 8 (or anything non-zero, really), and have a `fee_basis_points` param to work with that is of type `u16` with a minimum value of `0` and maximum value of `10000`, such that `0` == 0% fees and `10000` == 100% fees. In the contract logic, I want to transfer an arbitrary amount of tokens `X` to a PDA but want to make sure to apply `fee_basis_points` to the token amount (which is `u64`, ofc).

The intuitive thing approach when not worried about unsigned int math would simply be: `token_amount + (token_amount * (fee_basis_points/10000))` but using `checked_div` and `checked_mul` in the contract and trying the above formula clearly ignores all precision which is not what we want.

```
let amount: u64 = arbitrary_token_account.amount;
let fee: u16 = some_state.fee_basis_points;

// let amount_to_actually_transfer_in_cpi = ????;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let amount: u64 = arbitrary_token_account.amount;
let fee: u16 = some_state.fee_basis_points;

let amount_to_actually_transfer_in_cpi =  amount.checked_mul(fee).unwrap().checked_div(10000).unwrap();
```

seems to be it. not sure if im not accounting for something here though :/